# Why does "face" turn to "faced" when used as a compound adjective?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, word-usage, compounds

I ask this question out of curiosity more than anything. We use the word "face" as a noun, but when it is used in a compound adjective, it turns into "faced":

> The features of his **face** hardened.
>
> He was **stony-faced** when he gave his reply.
>
> The **crimson-faced** girl gestured for her friend to grab a bottle of water.

Does anyone have an explanation for why this happens?

Comment: Suffix "***-ed***" - past participle suffix of weak verbs, from Old English -ed, -ad, -od (leveled to -ed in Middle English), from Proto-Germanic *-da- (cognates: Old High German -ta, German -t, Old Norse -þa, Gothic -da, -þs), from PIE *-to-,***"suffix forming adjectives marking the accomplishment of the notion of the base"***  - http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-ed

Comment: Nothing special about face, is it? Left-handed, one-eyed, four-legged, slack-jawed, rosy-cheeked, strong-willed, weak-minded, red-headed . . .

Comment: Please visit [ell.se] -- there's nothing special about *face,* the *-ed* suffix has its uses. This Q is too elementary for ELU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suffix
***-ed***:

Etymology

> - From Middle English -ed, from Old English -od ‎(adjective suffix), from Proto-Germanic *-ōdaz*. While identical in appearance to the past participle of class 2 weak verbs, this suffix was attached directly to nouns without any intervening verb. Compare also Latin -ātus.
> - ***Used to form adjectives from nouns***, in the sense of having the object represented by the noun.
>
>   - *pointed (as in A needle has a pointed end. - the end of a needle has a point.)*
>   - *horned (as in a horned antelope - an antelope possessing horns)*
>
> As an extension of the above, when used along with an adjective preceding the noun, describes something that has an object of a particular quality.
>   red-haired (having red hair)
>
> - *left-handed (having a left hand as more dexterous hand)*